# VoLTE is working in preinstalled Cyanogen OS but not in CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, cyanogen-os, voice-over-lte

I was trying to use VoLTE in my phone but eventually landed up with result:

1. CyanogenOS can run VoLTE based SIM card
2. CyanogenMod can't run them.

Tried
1. Setting LTE Only option in `##4636##`
2. Setting APN in Sim Settings
3. Also kept the VoLTE in SIM Slot 1

But nothing worked in CyanogenMod.

Does any one have idea how to use both VoLTE and CyanogenMOD both?
Currently my phone's CyanogenOS is allowing me to keep only one at a time :)

But I want to use cyanogenMod as it is marshmallow and nightly build updates are released.

Answer (score -1):

Because CyanogenMod doesn't come with VoLTE soft function. You have to create your custom mod with this function, which is very difficult to do.

Comment: Hello and welcome to android enthusiasts! Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/156976/edit) your answer to include a source if possible and don't use caps lock in your answers.

Comment: Quoting [CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_opt_net_ims](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_opt_net_ims): *At the moment, this only supports VoLTE calls which is compliant to GSMA IR.92 specification.* So there is at least *some* VoLTE support. Also, [this Changelog for CM13](https://romhut.com/versions/cm-13-0-20160406-v6-0) mentions *add volte feature system property and api's* as well as *set volte feature enable in ImsManager when Volte service is updated bb7de1a telephony*. Side-marks point to a possible dependency on hardware/service.

Comment: This is what I've been curious about, the specific hardware and software requirements involved.

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable the internet option for the 4g sim, which you're using and restart the phone. This will only enable LTE not volte internet.